# How can I store elements to pass to .not()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I want to use `$( "#c1" ).parents()` with the `.not()` function.

I thought of storing the selector in a variable, something like this:

```
var ele = $( "#c1" ).parents();
```

But I didn't really know how to continue from here.

Comment: Please provide us a code because the question is too large for me. jsfiddle could be very great

Comment: You could try: `var ele=("#c1").parents(':not(theparent)');`. if you could explain more about your question then we will be able to answer it properly.

Comment: Since you use an id you only select 1 element. So using the not selector won't help.

Comment: what are you _actually_ trying to do?

Comment: No one noticed the missing `$` or `jQuery` prefix to get the element?

Comment: @morkro - I'm assuming a simple error when copy/pasting the code into the post....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use actual jQuery elements as parameters of the [`.not()` function:](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

> `.not( selector )`
>   Type: `Selector` or `Element` or **`Array`**
>   A string containing a selector expression, a DOM element, or **an array of elements to match against the set**.

Once you have a variable that contains all the relevant elements you want to exclude, just pass that variable to the `.not()` function. Consider this simplistic example:

```js
$(function(){
    var exclude_elems = $( ".bar" );
    var elems = $( ".foo" ).not( exclude_elems );
    // returns 3 as there are only 3 elements that do not contain the "bar" class
    alert( elems.length ); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo" />
<div class="foo" />
<div class="foo" />
<div class="foo bar" />
```